# Useradd command vs MySQL CREATE USER

Tags: linux, mysql

Do users and passwords created by `useradd` command in linux also register them with same creditionals in MySQL database?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Are you asking if the end result is the same, if the syntax is the same - or what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Thor Hi, I'm asking if I register a user with useradd, whether that user will also be registered in MySQL.

Comment: Fair enough; it'd probably be nice if you added that to your question, so that it is a bit more clear. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useradd` creates a local user that can potentially log in to a Unix/Linux system and execute commands from the command line, or may have access to FTP services, etc.

`CREATE USER`, which is a mySQL command, creates user accounts for the MySQL database only. One is not related to the other in any way. Permission changes applied to a Linux user do not reflect on MySQL users, and privileges granted to MySQL users apply only to MySQL tables and schemas.

The comparison is much like comparing apples with bricks.

Comment: But Apple devices are bricks...